# MySQL where clause with DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, date, between, date-range

I have a MySQL table with a date column.

I am trying select all the rows between some particular date range as,

```
select * from myTable mt 
    where DATE_FORMAT(mt.DateCol, '%y-%m-%b') between '01/03/2015' and '09/03/2015'
```

where `01/03/2015` and `09/03/2015` are from and to date range selected by user which is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and my datecolumn is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. So how can I directly select the rows using `DATE_FORMAT` function. The above query gives zero result.

Comment: Why would you expect a comparison of a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format with one in `mm/dd/yyyy` format to make any sense …?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And why would you convert a date to a string for this?  Just do:

```
select *
from myTable mt
where mt.DateCol between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-09';
```

If you like, you can add `date()` around the constants to emphasize their types:

```
select *
from myTable mt
where mt.DateCol between date('2015-03-01') and date('2015-03-09');
```

Comment: The date values `01/03/2015` and `09/03/2015` are coming in `dd/mm/yyyy` format via form submission. But me guess MySQL takes only in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` for comparison.

Comment: Myself trying to query without formatting the dates in codes.

Comment: @mpsbhat . . . Then convert the string parameters to dates use `str_to_date()`.

Comment: exactly... Myself wanted `str_to_date()` instead of `DATE_FORMAT()` as `select * from myTable mt where mt.DateCol between str_to_date('01/03/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date('09/03/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')`. Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

```
date_from="2021/10/28"
date_to="2021/10/31"
query = "select * from myTable mt where mt.date between str_to_date({a}{b}{c}, '%Y/%m/%d') AND str_to_date({d}{e}{f}, '%Y/%m/%d')".format(a="'",b=date_from,c="'",d="'",e=date_to,f="'")
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work: table parameters is (partners_id, created_at) table => scheme is master name is partners

```sql
select partners_id,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') = ('31-12-2014') from master.partners;
```

[image]